# T4MVC Base controller doesn't have default constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

My controller is inherited from anothe controller which doesn't have default constructor. T4MVC generates the following constructor which assumes base controller has default constructor:

```
protected MyControllerController(Dummy d) { }
```

How can I resolve this problem? Interesting enough, according to [this](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_History) page, version 2.4.00 "fixed issue when a base controller doesn't have a default ctor". I also [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730989/t4mvc-cannot-inherit-a-controller-class-which-has-no-default-constructor) this SO question, but my base controller is not generic.

Comment: I was able to repro your issue with version 2.10.0... I think you should post the issue on the T4MVC issue tracker, and until it fixed use the workaround from the linked SO question. Namely add a default constructor to your base class.

Comment: I'm out, but I'll try to investigate this toward the end of the week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work fine if you make your base controller abstract. I assume that it never needs to be used directly as a controller? If it does, then you can always create another non-abstract derived class to handle that.

Comment: Yeah, there is a couple ways to workaround it but I am working on the scenario (I have described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576606/asp-net-mvc-reuse-of-controllermodelviewroutes) which looks pretty reasonable. Wouldn't it be nice if T4MVC supported that without hacks?

Comment: Not following you here. Are you using the base type directly or not? If not, then marking it as abstract is not a hack, it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I am using it directly. I just pass some specific dependencies from derived controller to it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but marking it as abstract does *not* solve the problem. Adding an empty constructor will break dependency injection, so that is not an option either.

Comment: Are you saying that making it abstract has no effect on the generated code? I would expect that to cause a default ctor to be generated in the abstract base. Yet you are describing adding a default ctor as an *alternate* thing you tried, so something here doesn't add up.

Comment: -1 as it does not work if you make base constructor abstract:
  public abstract class BaseController : Controller
  {
    protected BaseController(ILogger logger);
  }
 public partial class HomeController : BaseController
 {
  public HomeController(ILogger logger)
   : base(logger)
  {
  }

  public virtual ActionResult Index()
  {
   return View();
  }
 }

Comment: Marking my base controller as `abstract` is also not working for me.